# Is it better to create objects containing functionality or have loose functions in AngularJS controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say we have three buttons on our site:

```
<button>Like</button>
<button>Dislike</button>
<button>Flag</button>
```

Each button will call their respective functions:

```
<button ng-click="like()">Like</button>
<button ng-click="dislike()">Dislike</button>
<button ng-click="flag()">Flag</button>
```

And in the controller it could look something like this:

```
$scope.like = function() {
  return likes + 1;
}

$scope.dislike = function() {
  return dislikes + 1;
}

$scope.flag = function() {
  return flags + 1;
}
```

Since cluttering the `$scope` with too many watchers is bad for performance, wouldn't it be better to do this:

```
$scope.actions = {
  like: function() {
    return likes + 1;
  },
  dislike: function() {
    return dislikes + 1;
  },
  flag: function() {
    return flags + 1;
  }
}
```

And then using it like:

```
<button ng-click="actions.like()">Like</button>
<button ng-click="actions.dislike()">Dislike</button>
<button ng-click="actions.flag()">Flag</button>
```

Which will reduce the number of watchers from *3* to *1*, also giving the benefit of creating grouped functionality. Leading to better readability as well.

From my point of view this makes more sense than having loose functions in your controller, especially since not all controllers can be made lightweight.

The thing that would make me doubt this approach is that I've never come across any examples whatsoever using this method. Is there a reason for this?

Which approach would be better to use in terms of commonly used design patterns, best practice and performance?

**EDIT:** There has been suggestions that I should instead use `controller as` syntax, I'm aware of this but this doesn't directly answer my question. As I would like to know which of the two methods that I've mentioned above is the better option, not using the `controller as` syntax.

Comment: The number of watchers not change. First I'm not sure but i thought that ng-click not add a watcher, but if it add, then both examples are exactly the same. The second is better to evict $scope issue (Names collisions).

Comment: The ng-click doesn't add it, but binding the functions does.

Comment: Well if you use the controller as syntax (That is the recommended way to prepare to migrate to angular 2). The this.like is register in the scope as $scope.vm.like, and looks like your approach.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I second what's been said above: ng-click does not create extra watchers. So your question doesn't make sense. The controllerAs syntax is recommended in several authoritative places, e.g. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @Ursus I never stated that the ng-click adds a watcher, I said binding a function using $scope.myFunction does. So instead creating an object using only one $scope would decrease the number of watchers, which makes sense if you think about it. My thought process could be completely wrong however, hence the posted question. So saying "you should use "controller as" syntax doesn't do it as a complete answer to me as I would like to know how Angular process my declarations and if not using controller as, which method should I be using.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz true. I never stated using the controllerAs syntax would be a complete answer though. That's why I put it in a comment.

Comment: @Ursus I understand that you weren't posting a real answer, but merely a recommendation. I'm just waiting on a complete answer that I feel can be accepted.

Comment: @Ursus Yes, http://plnkr.co/edit/AnqJwoaFAyAWFx86p7ws?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried out both your approaches and could not see any difference in performance. This is for two main practical reasons:

1. It is difficult to test performance of Angular applications, see [How to performance test an AngularJS Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219873/how-to-performance-test-an-angularjs-web-application).
2. It would make sense to test for performance only on a bigger scale application and not on such small examples.

I understand however that your question is about a proof of concept.
So, in theory, your second method is the better one because it pollutes the `$scope` less than the other and that's what's recommended.

In future, I would try the `controllerAs` syntax. Alternatively this is also interesting [if you're not a fan of that syntax](http://toddmotto.com/a-better-way-to-scope-angular-extend-no-more-vm-this/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting stuff that angular.extend thing, I'll have to try that one out. Thanks :)

Comment: @Chrillewoodz no probs. Interesting question too :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Jesús Quintana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121547/jes%C3%BAs-quintana) - the numbers of watchers not change.

Also, I advise you to use 'controller as' syntax. It's more conveniently to working for a few $scope's in your page.

For example, in your markup:

```
<div ng-controller='PageController as page'>
    <button ng-click="page.like()">Like</button>
    <button ng-click="page.dislike()">Dislike</button>
    <button ng-click="page.flag()">Flag</button>
</div>
```

And in code:

```
myApp.controller('PageController', function() {
    var page = this;

    page.like = function() {
       return page.likes + 1;
    }

    page.dislike = function() {
       return page.dislikes + 1;
    }

    page.flag = function() {
       return page.flags + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried the controller as syntax in the past but was not fond of it, it created problems when nesting ng-repeats amongst other things. Also I'm pretty certain that it's still in experimental state, is it not? Also this doesn't answer my question directly so I cannot accept it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz `controller as` hasn't been experimental for a long time now. It's even [recommend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) to use over the *traditional* syntax. That said, with angular2 you won't have controllers in your view anymore, so it's rather high-time to switch to the new syntax.

Comment: @Yoshi But if there won't be controllers why would there be a "controller as" syntax? How are controllers replaced?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz In angular2 everything will be components. With data bound to `this`. No more `$scope`. That's why it's useful to adopt `controller as` now, as it also binds to `this`. Reference: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/index.html

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I use 'controller as' syntax in a big project in my page controller and directives, and I think that is good practice. This syntax was experimental in v.1.1.5, but now we have 1.4.5! And I didn't get some troubles by use it. To answer your question: angular use $digest cycle for watching every controller's method in your markup and it is not depends on your style of variables/methods declaration. Is one rule: don't create many watchers in one scope and you don't have perfomance issues

Comment: Since I've written a big project not using controller as, and I'm not planning on rewriting it anytime soon before angular 2.0 is production ready, what would be the best approach out of the two I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz As you don't use `controller as` don't use the object. Why, because your view suddenly looks like you would use `controller as`. Which you can discern now, but maybe in a year, or maybe for someone maintaining the project after you, this could be problematic.

Comment: I agree, you don't need refactor. On my opinion you should use your second method, it is more clearly and closely to 'controller as' declaration. But you will not get better perfomance.